# C#'s System.IO.Path functionality in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, string, path

Does anybody knows for an implementation of Path manipulations functions in JS similar to C# System.IO.Path has?

I'm basically looking for Combine(string,string) and GetDirectoryName(string) functions.

Note: I don't want to manipulate the FileSystem (I can do it using FSO). I want sort of string manipulation implementation aimed to Paths.

Any help/link will be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: There are windows script components you can get at easily with vb script that can do this sort of stuff, but you will need to be running from a trusted zone and such.

Comment: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject.html

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't usually have access to the file system, so you are not likely to find this functionality without writing it yourself.  I'm not sure how localization would work either... would you use a / or a \ for the directory separator?